# How to write spring annotation for injecting collections?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reflection

Right now I'm creating validators for my project. There is one main validator which has more validators inside, here is an example:

```
@Component
public class MainValidator implements Validator {

    private final SubValidatorFirst subValidatorFirst;
    private final SubValidatorSecond subValidatorSecond;

    @Autowired
    public CompanyBranchValidator(SubValidatorFirst subValidatorFirst,
                                  SubValidatorSecond subValidatorSecond) {
        this.subValidatorFirst = subValidatorFirst;
        this.subValidatorSecond = subValidatorSecond;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return SomeClass.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        SomeClass obj = (SomeClass) target;
        subValidatorFirst.validate(obj, Errors errors);
        subValidatorSecond.validate(obj,  Errors errors);
        // etc....
    }
}
```

So the problem is that every time I have new sub validators, I need to change my main validator class and this breaks open-closed princile (if I understand it correctly)

So I've come up with another solution. I've created two annotations:

```
@Target(value = ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface EntitySubValidator {
    String validatorKey();
}

@Target(value = ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface InjectSubValidators {
    String validatorKey();
}
```

The `validatorKey` parameter in both annotations used to define to witch main validator this subvalidator belongs. With first annotation I mark every sub validator, with another one I'm injecting correct subvalidors to main validator into the collection. Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
@Service
@EntitySubValidator(validatorKey = "mainValidator")
public class SubValidatorFirst implements Validator {
    private final SomeServiceDependency someDependency;
    
    @Autowired
    public SubValidatorFirst(SomeServiceDependency someDependency) {
        this.someDependency = someDependency;
    }

    // No code for breavity
}

@Service
@EntitySubValidator(validatorKey = "mainValidator")
public class SubValidatorSecond implements Validator {
    private final SomeServiceDependency someDependency;
    
    @Autowired
    public SubValidatorSecond(SomeServiceDependency someDependency) {
        this.someDependency = someDependency;
    }

    // No code for breavity
}
```

And here is injecting example:

```
@Component
public class MainValidator implements Validator {
    @InjectSubValidators(validatorKey = "mainValidator")
    private List<Validator> subValidators = new ArrayList<>();
 
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return SomeClass.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        for (Validator validator : subValidators) validator.validate(target, 
        errors);
    }
}
```

I'm tried to add support for my annotations by using `BeanPostProcessro` like this:

```
@Component
public class InjectSubValidatorsBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        Field[] fields = bean.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(InjectSubValidators.class)) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                InjectSubValidators annotation = field.getAnnotation(InjectSubValidators.class);
                Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.manageemployee.employeemanagement");
                Set<Class<?>> subValidators = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(EntitySubValidator.class);
                List<Validator> validators = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Class<?> clazz : subValidators) {
                    if (clazz.getAnnotation(EntitySubValidator.class).validatorKey().equals(annotation.validatorKey())) {
                        try {
                            validators.add((Validator) clazz.newInstance());
                        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                }

                ReflectionUtils.setField(field, bean, validators);
            }
        }
        
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

But the problem is that I'm inserting value into the collection by using `Class#newInstance` so sprig simply will not manage it and because of this it will not have any dependencies injected in. What can I do to fix that issue?

Comment: Can't you just make both types components and let Spring inject the `List` with `@Autowired`/constructor injection?

Comment: That is why `@Qualifier` exists. Make different annotations for different types and just use `@Autowired` with a collection combined with the specific `@Qualifier` you need. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @dan1stiscrying you mean that i should just inject them in `List<Validator>`  ? Well, what if i have more subvalidators for different validators? Then they are all will be injected into the wrong validator

Comment: @M.Deinum how can I use `@Qualifier` with my annotations? I though it's being used for injecting bean with unique id which you can specify, for example, in `@Component`, no? I can't really understand how can I use `@Qualifier` in my case if i can have a lot of validators and a lot of subvalidators for each validator. Right now I picked the solution wich Andrew S suggested, but it's not really what i want because I don't really like to create a lot of interfaces for them to be only markers. I'm really interested in solving this problem with custom annotations, but still didn't find how

Comment: You can also create an interface of the validators you want to inject as explained in [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77883077/10871900) by [Andrew S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6650475/andrew-s).

Comment: You are wrong about `@Qualifier` (as many people are as they have the false assumption that it is used to inject beans with names). You can create an annotation, which you annotate itself with `@Qualifier`. You then annotate your validator with that specific annotation as well as the collection (or the type in the collection) on the injection point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what `@Qualifier` exists for. You (and many with you) are under the false assumption that it is used for injection based on a specific name. But it isn't, actually that is only a side effect and not its actually purpose at all. How to use it is actually explained in [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/annotation-config/autowired-qualifiers.html) (which you did bother to read didn't you?!).

What you can do is create your own custom annotation(s) and annotate them with `@Qualifier` and use them both on your type as well as the collection type you want to inject.

Something like this.

```java
@Target(value = {ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType. PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Validator {

  String validatorKey();

}
```

Now you can annotate both your validators as injection points with this to get the proper one.

```java
@Component
@Validator(validatorKey="mainValidator")
public class MyValidator1 implements Validator {}
```

Then in your place where you want it

```java
@Component
public class MyBigRootValidator implements Validator {

  @Autowired
  @Validator(validatorKey="mainValidator")
  private List<Validator> subValidators;

}
```

Something along those lines. I've written this from the top of my head so it might be that you need to write `List<@Validator(validatorKey="mainValidator")` instead of annotation the actual list.

So you don't need to re-invent the wheel it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Custom annotations are not necessary - use different interfaces to give Spring hints for how to wire up the dependencies.  For example, given some class that needs to be validated:

```
public class ClassA {
    ...
}
```

and the Validator interface (but made generic):

```
public interface Validator<T> {
    void validate(T target, Errors errors);
}
```

then extend to create a marker interface to give Spring a hint to wire up the dependencies:

```
public interface ClassAValidator extends Validator<ClassA> { }
```

with a concrete `Validator` for `ClassA`

```
@Component   
public class ClassAVaValidator1 implements ClassAValidator  {
    void validate(ClassA target, Errors errors) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and another concreate `Validator` for `ClassA`

```
@Component   
public class ClassAVaValidator2 implements ClassAValidator  {
    void validate(ClassA target, Errors errors) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And might as well use a base class to avoid code duplication:

```
public class ValidatorHandler<T> implements Validator<T>  {
    private final List<Validator<T>> validators;

    public ClassAVaValidationHandler(List<T> validators) {
       this.validators = validators;
    }

    public void validate(T target, Errors errors) {
         validators.forEach(v -> validate(target, errors);
    }
}
```

So then:

```
@Componenet
public class ClassAValidationHandler extends ValidatorHandler<ClassA> {

   public ClassAValidationHandler(List<ClassAValidators> validators) {
        super(validators);
   }
}
```

will have the `List<ClassAValidators>` injected into its constructor.  And adding any new class which implements `ClassAValidator` (and annotated with @Component) will be included in `ClassAValidationHandler`'s constructor.

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking about something like this, but I didn't like the idea of creating marker class for each new validator (for example, what if I had ClassB, C, D, E etc?). There will be too much not really useful interfaces, but now i think that this solution is the easiest one, so i think i will stay with it for awhile. Still I am interested in creating my own annotations, yeah, this is not really needed now, but now it's a question of interest ahahah.

Comment: You could create an interface for each type of validator where you want to inject multiple validators together. You can also otherwise specify how to group them (e.g. by creating a custom collection bean).